# Pyodbc installation error on Ubuntu 16.04 with Sql Server installed

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am trying to test my scripts for data migration from `mssql-server` to `oracle server`. For this, I have to install `pyodbc` `python` package for **Ubuntu**, it has the dependency of `unixodbc`. When I try to install `unixodbc-dev` using:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

It gives **broken packages error**:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unixodbc-dev : Depends: unixodbc (= 2.3.1-4.1)
                Depends: odbcinst1debian2 (= 2.3.1-4.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But with *aptitude* (`sudo aptitude install unixodbc-dev`) it is **installing** and **also removing some SQL server files** due to which my `SQL-server` goes down.

Again on installing `SQL server` with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mssql-server mssql-tools -y
```

it removes `unixodbc`:

```
Removing unixodbc-dev (2.3.1-4.1) ...
Removing unixodbc (2.3.1-4.1) ...
Removing libodbc1:amd64 (2.3.1-4.1) ...
Removing odbcinst (2.3.1-4.1) ...
Removing odbcinst1debian2:amd64 (2.3.1-4.1) ...
```

Hence again, I am left only with `SQL-server` and **no** `unixodbc`(*pyodbc doesn't works*). I understand that there is some dependency issue between both of the packages.

Is there is a way to Install both on the same machine or do I have to use 2 machines here?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to install pyodbc from the Ubuntu repositories. Have you tried installing it using pip to see if that works any better?

Comment: @GordThompson Yes, I did `pip install pyodbc` only, but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I've got the solution from [Microsoft's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) only.
Here is the method for setting up `unixodbc` with mssql on `Ubuntu 16.04`:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev-utf16
```

After this, I can easily install `pyodbc` with:

```
pip install pyodbc
```

There are listed ways on this [Microsoft's webpage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) for using and installing the `Microsoft ODBC Driver` for `SQL Server` for Popular Linux systems.

---

Here is the easiest installation method for on `Ubuntu 16.04` that I've found:

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql mssql-tools
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev-utf16 #this step is optional but recommended*
```

Comment: Future readers should go to the [Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454(v=sql.110).aspx) for the latest information on how to install msodbcsql and related components. They are under active development and the instructions have already been updated several times since this answer was written.

Comment: Although Microsoft documentation says it's optional, for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS you must install sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

Answer (score 7):

I do not have Sql server installed but when I want to install pyodbc at new machine, I can't install it as well. Someone suggest the following (I can't exactly tell where I find it):

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
sudo pip install pyodbc
```