# Facing obstacle to install pyodbc and pymssql in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu

I want to install pyodbc for connection mssql server using sqlalchemy
I am googling and tried in several ways like

```
pip install pyodbc
```

Followed this link  [Pyodbc installation error on Ubuntu 16.04 with Sql Server installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234174/pyodbc-installation-error-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-sql-server-installed)
but have not solved
below type error thrown

```
src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyodbc
```

Comment: Per the question you referenced, did you install unixODBC before trying to install pyodbc via pip? `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev`

Comment: jinksPadlock Yes I have installed unixODBC before pyodbc

Comment: i have used sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev and pip install pyodbc for installation but it shows bellow error ""No driver name specified; " (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') "

Comment: Are you specifically naming the Driver? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For pyodbc case
 I used command

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
pip install pyodbc
```

and able to success pyodbc installation but facing my comment problem (not able to push data into mssql server)

For pymssql i used command

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
pip install pymssql
```

then able to success pymssql installation and data insert into mssql server

Answer (score 2):

For RH/Cent-OS/Linux use,

```
yum install unixODBC
yum install unixODBC-devel
```

Comment: do upvote the accepted answer that is helpful i tested

Answer (score 0):

**Try this without utf16:**

According to @jinksPadlock I have successfully installed:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Comment: i have used  sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev and pip install pyodbc for installation but it shows bellow error ""No driver name specified; "
(pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
"

Comment: Did you figure out your issue @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Comment: @Dude0001 yes I solved and put my answer as well