# Installing pyodbc failed on Linux

Tags: python

I just run this command:

```
sudo pip install pyodbc
```

then I get below message and error:

```
steven81@PythonWEBVM:~$ sudo pip install pyodbc
The directory '/home/steven81/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/steven81/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pyodbc
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/71/cef225c4889620a1a00251d24c1746fe0cf4124290a75d1c2dc5c187b61f/pyodbc-4.0.23.tar.gz (215kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 13.5MB/s
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
  Running setup.py install for pyodbc ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-NR7ytY/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-voJYBN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'pyodbc' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DPYODBC_VERSION=4.0.23 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/pyodbcmodule.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pyodbcmodule.o -Wno-write-strings
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    In file included from src/pyodbcmodule.cpp:11:0:
    src/pyodbc.h:56:17: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-NR7ytY/pyodbc/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-voJYBN/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-NR7ytY/pyodbc/
```

I saw there is an error:

command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
then I search in on google, it asked to run this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

so, I run this but get below message:

```
steven81@PythonWEBVM:~$ sudo apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.12-1~16.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

so what's the problem and how to install pyodbc correctlly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facing obstacle to install pyodbc and pymssql in ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303870/facing-obstacle-to-install-pyodbc-and-pymssql-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking for the pyodbc install to connect to SQLServer from Linux(ubuntu).

sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev

sudo apt-get install python3-dev

python3 -m pip install pyodbc

Comment: Doesn't work under venv. I have everything installed OUTSIDE of venv but looks like they don't carry over into venv. Linux is such a beast to play with...

Comment: @Nicholas Humphrey, it would be great to pass link to installed version of unixodbc-dev into venv. I do struggle to find any information how to do it.